# MySQL Grouping of data

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I want to group my data by Age and by gender: like this sample data:

```
Age: 1
      Male: 2
      Female: 3
      Age 1 Total: 5

Age: 2
      Male: 6
      Female: 3
      Age 2 Total: 9
```

How can I group the data according to age and count all the male and females in that age from mysql database?

Answer (score 11):

```
SELECT
  age,
  SUM(CASE WHEN gender = 'male' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) males,
  SUM(CASE WHEN gender ='female' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) females,
  COUNT(*) total
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY age
```

Comment: +1 This is the correct answer.  Though because the OP is using MySQL, I will shorten that to `Select age, sum(gender ='male')  males, sum(gender ='female')  females, count(*) total from yourtable a group by age`

Answer (score 7):

```
Select age, gender, Count(*) cnt
From your_table
Group By age, gender
```

will get you

```
Age  Gender   cnt
  1  Male     2
  1  Female   3
  2  Male     6
  2  Female   9
```

You should be able to sum the counts per age in PHP afterwards.